# Moshe Rabainu burning his mouth with the coals

Tags: midrash, moshe-rabbeinu, hands-fingers, fire-burning, injury

Per this answer [Moshe and the Red-Hot Coals](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13453/moshe-and-the-red-hot-coals/13455#13455) Moshe Rabainu took the coals and placed it in his mouth and his mouth got burned. It does not mention that his hand got burned. Did his hand get burned or not? If it did, why is it not mentioned, if it did not, why did only his mouth get burned?

Comment: maybe the Midrash is telling us the details that explain his speech impediment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why Moses mouth got burned was to atone for the milk of the non jewish women that touched his tongue. His hand did not get burned because it did not require atonement.

I saw this in some book, i think Vedibarta Bam.

Comment: Interesting, I have actually seen sources that say that Moses even as a child refused to nurse from non-jewesses, which is why Yochebed was enlisted to be his wet nurse.

Comment: See Rashi citing Midrash Rabah and Talmud Sotah: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=22

Comment: I don't understand. I thought that he didn't actually nurse from non-Jewish women. (I think it's in the Gemara toward the beginning of Sotah.)

Comment: It's true he refused, however the milk still touched his tongue and he spat it out. According to that sefer at least.